# Django. Restrict each user to only vote once

Tags: django, django-models

I have a situation and am happy with either one of two solutions, depending on which is more feasible/possible. I have a page that displays an event. That event's name may not necessarily be correct, and so users have the option to suggest corrections. Those corrections are stored in their own table with an Foreign Key relationship to the event. Once a suggestion has been made, users can vote up or down on the suggestion. I need to restrict each logged in user's maximum vote to 1. I don't have the slightest idea how to do this.

My ideal solution: There are as many as five suggestions displayed. Each logged in user can vote on each of these five suggestions. Once on each.

My less ideal, but still acceptable solution: There are as many as five suggestions displayed. A logged in user is allowed to vote up or down on only one of the five suggestions.

I'm not sure which is more practical. I'll provide my models for the event and the suggested name. Please let me know if there's something else you need to see. Thanks in advance!

```
class Event(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
    id = models.BigIntegerField(blank = 'TRUE', primary_key='TRUE')
    version = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    views = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable = False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField()
    trained = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    type = models.SmallIntegerField(default = 0)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = datetime.datetime.today()
        self.modified = datetime.datetime.today()
        super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class suggestedName(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE', null = 'TRUE')
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

Comment: You are not keeping track of `user` who has voted anywhere.

Comment: To limit number of votes, you need a model for the Vote entity with user details in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Vote(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('userprofile','suggestedName'),)

    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    suggestedName = models.ForeignKey(suggestedName)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

As some comments suggest, you should have a model for your `User` (which, in my example, I'm simply assuming you already have).

What can you do with this model? Exactly what you need to do!

Suppose you have a view that allows a user to vote. You'd want to override its `post()` (or `is_valid()`, it depends) method to check if the user can vote or not:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # - retrieve the user_profile
    # - retrieve the suggestedName he voted for
    # - query the votes to see if this combination of user_profile + suggestedName already exists

    vote, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(
                        userprofile=userprofile, 
                        suggestedName=suggestedName, 
                        event=event
                    )

    # get_or_create will return a tuple
    # where created is True if the method created the Vote
    # False if there was a vote for this user and this name already
    # You now want to use the value from 'created' 
    # to decide wether the vote is valid or not

    if not created:
       return HttpResponse('You already voted for this, cheater')
    else:
       return HttpResponse('Awesome, thanks for voting!')
```

Furthermore, if you want to allow just 1 vote per user, pass to `get_or_created` just your retrieved user value.

Hope these guidelines help you out a bit :)

Comment: Yes, perfect. Sorry about using `User` which, I realize, can be confusing. Don't take my code as 'perfect', just use it as a guide line to understand how this can work (a.k.a. : does it all makes sense?)

Comment: does your post() method go into the `Vote` model or into a view with voting capabilities?

Comment: The view with voting capabilities, models don't have a `post` method :)

Comment: Hey, so I've been working with your answer and it's great. I can tell I'm getting close, but I was thinking, won't `get_or_create` always return true? Because if the user hasn't voted, it'll create it and it will exist. If the user has, it'll "get" it and it'll still exist? I also wasn't quite sure why you had `vote, created` instead of just `created`.

Comment: read the docs :) get_or_create returns a tuple: the object and a boolean, that evaluates to True if it was created, False if it was already there. That's why you can rely on it! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: PS: read the comments in my code, so far all your questions found answers there :)

Comment: Oh, how silly. I just got it to work. Definitely understand your code a lot better now. Thanks so much for the simple and ideal solution!