# Django. Multiple OneToOneField in the same model

Tags: python, django, model

I have a User model and an Article model. I would like the users to vote only once for an article. So I want to create a Vote model which is related only once with the user model, and only once with the article model.

How can I do this ? Is it possible to use multiple OneToOneField in the Vote model like this :

```
class Vote(models.Model):

    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User)
    article_id = models.OneToOneField(Article)
    vote = models.BooleanField()
```

I also saw this method ([Django. Restrict each user to only vote once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864783/django-restrict-each-user-to-only-vote-once)) :

```
class Vote(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user_id','article_id'),)

    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    article_id = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    vote = models.BooleanField()
```

Which one is the best ?

Thanks

Comment: as Jose Romero says in his answer, the second one is best because the first one is wrong, it doesn't achieve what you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the best you can do is the second one. Because in the first one you can only have one vote in one article. In the second one you can have many votes in one article but one vote can only be related to one article. That I think is what you want.